# Multiple where clauses in foreach statement c#

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I have the following statement:

```
foreach (var textBlock in scoresGrid.Children.OfType<TextBlock>().Where(three => three.Name.Contains("Three")))
```

How am I able to make it so that I can make it so it's `where name contain three or four`?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget C# is Case Sensitive so you might want to use three.Name.ToLower().Contains(...) unless you're certain of the case of the control names in the gridview. Are these static or dynamic?

Comment: 1) this is not really `foreach`-related, but rather LINQ. 2) You can simply do this with binary operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use or `||` operator to combine the conditions in where clause.

```
foreach (var textBlock in scoresGrid.Children.OfType<TextBlock>()
           .Where(three => three.Name.Contains("Three") || three.Name.Contains("Four")))
```

Comment: That works great thanks! I will make it accepted after the silly 12 minute wait. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] names = { "Three", "Four" } ;
foreach (var textBlock in scoresGrid.Children.OfType<TextBlock>()
                   .Where(tb => names.Any(name => tb.Name.Contains(name))))
```

Also I think your foreach statement is kind of hard to read. Get filtered textBlocks first. Then iterate them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logic operators. For or it is '||' 
`>().Where(three => three.Name.Contains("Three") || three.Name.Contains("Four")))`